# Retornar PartialView com validações para uma Modal ASP MVC 4

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Tenho uma tela Index, onde está a tabela das pessoas cadastradas, na mesma tela tenho um botão novo que chama uma Modal(boostrap) dessa forma:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Add", "Pessoa", new { area = "Gestor" })" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPessoa">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Novo
</a>
```

e a controller retorna `return PartialView("Partial/ModalPessoa");`

O conteúdo da ModalPessoa é um formulário com vários campos que são obrigatórios, quando é dado submit vai para a controller que está dessa forma:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
return PartialView("Partial/ModalPessoa", model);
```

, mas ele retorna só a partial sem style ou script nenhum, ao invez de retornar essa partial para dentro da Modal, alguém sabe como fazer o retorno do conteúdo da partial para dentro da modal com as validações feitas no servidor?

Comment: Thiago estás a usar ajax? o que tu queres é carregar esse conteúdo sem dar refresh à página certo? Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6634/129

Answer (score 1):

Se a ideia é trazer uma Modal para cadastro de novos registros, o uso de *Partials* interagindo com o *Controller* é desnecessário. Como boa prática, o Modal pode ficar escondido e ser exibido através de evento JS simples.

Para exibir a validação em caso de erros, há três alternativas:

- Usar o jQuery.Validation para validar o máximo de informações possível na tela;
- [Fazer o POST por Ajax e trabalhar o JSON de retorno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34807/como-fazer-retorno-com-ajax-beginform);
- Fazer o POST normal, e reexibir o Modal em caso de erros de validação.