# HiddenFor - Submit perde valor na primeira vez

Tags: jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue código:

**Index:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="modal fade" id="minhaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="conteudoModal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="myclick">click me</button>
</div>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#myclick").click(function () {
        $("#conteudoModal").load("@Url.Action("_minhaPartialView", "Home")", function () {
            $("#minhaModal").modal("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**_minhaPartialView:**

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Modelos

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "OnBegin_Function", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess_Function" }, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Título</h4>
    </div>

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyProperty)

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">

 function OnBegin_Function() {
     $('#MyProperty').val(123);
    }

    function OnSuccess_Function() {

    }

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _minhaPartialView()
{
    var model = new Modelos
    {
        MyProperty = 1
    };

    return PartialView(model);
}

public ActionResult MyAction(Modelos model)
{
    // aqui retorna model.MyProperty = 1 na primeira vez.
    // o certo é retornar valor 123, por exemplo
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Problema:**

Quando faço "submit", o valor retorna 1 na primeira vez. Na segunda vez retorna valor 123.

**UPDATE:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#MyProperty').val(123);  //AQUI FUNCIONA !!!
});

function OnBegin_Function() {  //NÃO FUNCIONA
    $("#MyProperty").val(123);      
}
```

Comment: Você esta fazendo a requisição via `ajax` ?

Comment: Veja se pode te ajudar [Como fazer retorno com Ajax BeginForm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/34823/60376) essa resposta tem dois jeitos de fazer a requisição.

Comment: Sim, nessa resposta ele está mostrando como enviar o *form* para o servidor e receber o retorno dele.

Comment: estranho sua tentativa com o `.val()` não funcionar, aqui no meu código tenho esse campo `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Radius)`, e no JS faço isso `$('#Radius').val($(this).val());`, ele recebe o valor digitado em um input, importante dizer que isso só é possivel tambem depois que a tela estiver toda carregada, coloque isso em um `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda não seria melhor você colocar o `Javascript` completo na pergunta ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tendo esse problema por que está tentando mudar um valor do formulário depois de disparar o "OnBegin".

Segundo a [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onbegin(v=vs.118).aspx):

> The JavaScript function is called by ASP.NET MVC after the HttpRequest object is instantiated but before it is invoked

Logo, essa propriedade é chamada após a serialização do formulário. Levando isso em consideração, não é possível a mudança no recebimento do dado no seu Controller, apenas no seu input. Tente mudar os valores antes da serialização do seu `form`.

Comment: Fiquei dia inteiro me matando aqui, obrigado pela resposta útil.